# Clipboard viewer for programming purposes

Tags: string, clipboard, viewer, devtools

I need a clipboard viewer in order to understand the type and contents of the data I'm receiving. Is there any such program available, (for Windows) that lets you explore any type of data currently in the clipboard?

***ClipSpy:*** Unfortunately the only workable multi-format viewer, [ClipSpy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/clipboard/clipspy.aspx), shows me the string data wrapped every 10 characters, and expands the hex and binary views which I'm not concerned about.

Comment: Sounds like we need a *nix ClipSpy too, just putting it out in the world, would be a good project for someone to work on if one were bored, the world would benefit from it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start -> Run -> clipbrd

Comment: Fair enough, though it shows many formats greyed-out (disabled and therefore unavailable for viewing).

Answer (score 2):

I would use the command-line [clipboard](http://www.steve.org.uk/Software/clipboard/) tool to send the clipboard contents to a file.  Then you view/parse it using any old tool.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) which uses an SQL lite database. I am sure you could figure out a way to manipulate the stored data for syntax highlighting or modify the program so that when editing clips it would open with syntax highlighting or in an editor that has it.